# Replace values in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and working on my first spark project where I am facing two issues.

a) not able to reference column using

```
df["col1"].show() 

***TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable***
```

b) not able to replace values in my spark dataframe with aggregated value like mean

```
Code:
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row, HiveContext, SQLContext, Column
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = hive_context.table("db_new.temp_table")
df.select("col1").fillna(df.select("col1").mean())

***AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mean'***
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update:

I tried the below code snippet but it is returning another error.

```
df.withColumn("new_Col", when("ColA".isNull,df.select(mean("ColA"))
  .first()(0).asInstanceOf[Double])
  .otherwise("ColA"))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isNull'
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
df[["col1"]].show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That resolved my first issue. Any suggestions on the 2nd one?

Comment: sorry didn't see the second bit, I think the second part was answered in the comments to your question